# Problem with my Native C++ Addon in Electron in Mac

Tags: c++, electron, dylib, node.js-addon, n-api

I am writing code to load c++ dynamic library from electron. When trying it in Mac I get the following error:

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN15FcDrive2Library13InitDrive2LibEv
  Referenced from: /Users/nikhell/Documents/Codelathe/Workspace/cl-fc-client/electron-drive-client/build/Release/electronToCppBridge.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

My binding.gyp file looks like this:

```
{
    "targets":[
    {
        "target_name": "electronToCppBridge",
        "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        'include_dirs': [
            "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
        ],
        'dependencies': [
            "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
        ],
        'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ],
        "copies":[
        {
            'destination': './node_modules/electron/dist',
            'files':[
                '../../cl-fc-client/release/support/common/clientca.pem',
                '../../cl-fc-client/release/support/common/clientcert.pem',
                '../../cl-fc-client/clouddrive2/config.xml',
                '../../cl-fc-client/release/support/prebuilt/translationsdc.zip'
            ]
        },
        {                        
            'destination': './src',
            'files':['../cloudDrive2Lib/LibraryEntry/cloudDrive2Library.h']
        }
        ],
        "conditions":[
            ["OS=='win'", 
            {
                "copies":[
                { 
                    'destination': './build/Release',
                    'files':[
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/bugtrap/BugTrapU-x64.dll',
                        '../build/bin/msvc/Release64/cloudDrive2Lib.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/x86_64-win32/ssleay32MD.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoZip64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoXML64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoUtil64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoNetSSL64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoNet64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoJSON64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoFoundation64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/bin64/PocoCrypto64.dll',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/openssl/1.0.2j/lib/x86_64-win32/libeay32MD.dll'
                    ]
                },
                {                        
                    'destination': './libs',
                    'files':['../build/bin/msvc/Release64/cloudDrive2Lib.lib']
                },
                ],
                "sources": [
                    "src/electronToCppBridge.cc",
                ],
            }
            ],
            ["OS=='mac'",
            {
                "copies":[
                {
                    'destination': './build/Release',
                    'files':[
                        '../build/bin/darwin/release/libfileclouddrive2lib.dylib',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/lib/Darwin/x86_64/libPocoCrypto.45.dylib',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/lib/Darwin/x86_64/libPocoFoundation.45.dylib',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/lib/Darwin/x86_64/libPocoJSON.45.dylib',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/lib/Darwin/x86_64/libPocoNet.45.dylib',
                        '../../cl-fc-client-thirdparty/poco/1.7.5/lib/Darwin/x86_64/libPocoNetSSL.45.dylib'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'destination': './libs',
                    'files':[
                        '../build/bin/darwin/release/libfileclouddrive2lib.dylib'
                    ]
                },
                ],
                "sources": [
                    "src/electronToCppBridge.cc",
                    "libs/libfileclouddrive2lib.dylib",
                ],                    
            }
            ]            
        ],
    }       
    ]
}
```

Its working in windows. In Mac I have tried reinstalling the node modules and electron-rebuild also. None of them works for me. Th dylib is getting copied successfully besides the native .node module. Dont know why this link error is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I realized that the link_dependencies tag needs to be added in binding.gyp. Also the dylib needs to be copied at the root of the project.